.next/static/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory) , NextJs Deployment on plesk server
I try to deploy a nextJs app on plesk server.
Next Js Setup on Plesk
Error showing on log
But I'm facing this error continuosly. Which say nextJs not able to find index.html file.
